Conjugate to transpose via symmetric matrix
I am wondering for which square matrices $A \in M_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ there exists an invertible symmetric matrix $S \in GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ such that
$$S^{-1}AS = A^t?$$
It is a classical result, over any coefficient field, that $A$ can be conjugated to its transpose, but the question above asks when this can be done via a symmetric matrix. The question is only non-trivial for non-symmetric matrices $A$.

The required symmetric transition matrix $S$ always exists. See the list of references given in the first paragraph of Olga Taussky, The Role of Symmetric Matrices in the Study of General Matrices, Linear Algebra and Its Applications, 5:147-154, 1972.

Thank yu for this useful reference !
